# Pandoc: get array size

Tags: pandoc

In pandoc, I can iterate through an array like this:

```
$for(author)$
  $author$
$endfor$
```

Which works fine. What is the best way to get the size of the array? The reason is that in my template, I would like to do one thing if there is only a single author, and do something else if there are more than one authors.

Answer (score 0):

According to a message from September 2015, a length attribute of arrays **is not available** within the Pandoc template language.

Source: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2416

Answer (score 0):

In a later version of Pandoc (> 2.10), you can use [pipe](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pipes) in templates. You can get the length/size of the array using

```
$author/length$
```